# How to define invariant of python binsearch algorithm from lib?

Tags: python, algorithm

I found the following code in python [lib](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/bisect.py):

```
def bisect_left(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if a[mid] < x: lo = mid+1
        else: hi = mid
    return lo
```

Return the index where to insert item x in list a, assuming a is sorted.
The return value i is such that all e in a[:i] have e < x, and all e in
a[i:] have e >= x.

What is an invariant of this algorithm? I wanna to understand that it is correct.

Comment: hi is always greater or equal to lo is an invariant of this algorithm

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is known as [Binary Search Alorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). It works on sorted list to find an element in O(logn) (normally finding an element in a list requires O(n) to iterate over all elements). The magic behind it is as follows: Suppose you have a sorted array from 1 to 1000. you want to check whether 247 is exist or not, one way is iterate over all elements but the the other is using BST i.e. check the median value, if it is greater than 247, It means that if 247 exist on this array it should be placed somewhere in the first have of the array and in this way you simply ignore the second half and so on.